# How to return from anonymous method

Tags: c#

I have to implement the following function in a way that executes asynchronously but still returns bool when it finishes depending on the result

```
public bool Handler(JObject data, CefCallback callback)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        return true;
    }).Unwrap().ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        return false;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

however i don't know how to return from inside the anonymous method

Comment: Have you tried await/async? This would pretty much solve the problem completley.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i know about async/await but unfortunately i can't use it in this situation... something related to cefglue's structure. So i have to workaround to handle the request asynchronously and still use async/await with my old functions.

Comment: This just doesn't make sense. Why have asynchronous code at all if you're dealing with other code that just plain cannot handle it? Just keep it all synchronous.

Comment: @hvd and screw the ui ?... also all of my code is depending on async/await so i want any hack or something that achieves what i want.

Comment: @DanielEugen You wouldn't need to screw the UI; you would be able to use synchronous code in a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function to be asynchronous it will need to return a `Task<bool>` not a `bool`.  For the method to return a `bool` means that it needs to have computed the result by the time it returns to its caller.  The literal definition of an asynchronous method is a method that computes its value *after* returning to its caller.

Comment: i know about async/await but unfortunately i can't use it in this situation... something related to cefglue's structure. So i have to workaround to handle the request asynchronously and still use async/await with my old functions.

Comment: @DanielEugen You don't need to use `await` but you *do* need to return a `Task` if you want the method to be asynchronous.  If you *must* return a `bool` then it is impossible, by definition, for the method to be asynchronous.

Comment: @Servery so there is no way i can return or give out the result to the caller without using await ?... and without blocking

Comment: @DanielEugen I specifically said that you don't need to use `await`.  There are any number of ways of making a program asynchronous, and using `await` is just one.  You *do* need to change the signature of the method; there is no way around that.

Comment: sorry but what should i do to provide a delayed reply for the caller function ?

Comment: @DanielEugen You'll need to do exactly what I told you that you'd need to do.  Return a `Task`.  Of course, there are alternatives, but what you absolutely cannot do is return a `bool`, under any circumstances, and have your method be asynchronous.  Repeating the question over and over doesn't change the answer.

Comment: sorry to annoy you man... didn't mean to repeat the question but to clarify my idea.